# I want Slidable in flutter on top of the container , not to move it away

Tags: flutter

I want to keep the Container and slide the delete icon on top of it like this in the picture so that when i scroll the item   the delete icon and any other icon appers on top of the container without margining it to the left.

Please need help with it  Please need help with it

[image]

here is my code

```
ListView.builder(
                          itemCount: _prefsManager.campaings.length + 1,
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                            if (index == _prefsManager.campaings.length) {
                              return ListTile(
                                title: IconButton(
                                  icon: Icon(
                                    Icons.add,
                                    color: Colors.deepPurple,
                                  ),
                                  onPressed: () {
                                    _AddPrize();
                                  },
                                ),
                              );
                            } else {
                              return Slidable(
                                // dragStartBehavior: DragStartBehavior.down,
                                key: Key(_prefsManager.campaings[index]), // Unique key for each item
                                direction: Axis.horizontal,
                                startActionPane: ActionPane(
                                  // extentRatio: 0.1,
                                  motion: StretchMotion(),
                                  children: [
                                    SlidableAction(

                                      flex: 2,
                                      onPressed: (BuildContext context) {
                                        _showConfirmationDialog(context, () {
                                          // This is the callback function that will be called if the user confirms.
                                          setState(() {
                                            campaings.removeAt(index);
                                            _prefsManager.campaings = campaings; // Update SharedPreferencesManager
                                            _prefsManager.saveCampaings(); // Save to SharedPreferences
                                          });
                                        });
                                      },

                                      backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                                      icon: Icons.delete,
                                      label: 'Delete',
                                    )

                                  ],
                                ),
                                child: Container(
                                  width: 285.w,
                                  height: 50.h,
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.r),
                                  ),
                                  child: GestureDetector(
                                    onTap: () {
                                      Navigator.of(context).push(_createRoute(index));
                                    },
                                    child: Center(
                                      child: Text(
                                        _prefsManager.campaings[index],
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                          color: Colors.black,
                                          fontSize: 13.sp,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              );
                            }
                          },
                        )
```

Comment: Don't spam sentences in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Dismissible` widget, wrap ListTile by Dismissible widget

Reffer documentation https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/gestures/dismissible